# Couldn't connect web socket client to websocket server on local host windows 10

Tags: python-2.7, websocket, windows-10, loopback

I have an application signed for microsoft store which starts a web socket server on localhost (0.0.0.0:8081) on launching. Then I run python script with websocket client on the same host and try to connect to server (ws://127.0.0.1:8081) and it couldn't connect. But I can connect without any problems if I run this python script from another PC. Actually it works fine on local PC on another platforms: Win7, MacOS.

What i tried:

- disabled windows firewall and defender
- tried to add exception for application using CheckNetIsolation LoopbackExempt
- tried to connect using different ip (0.0.0.0, 127.0.0.1, pc name)

It seems like I have to switch/set on/off some option for application or win10, but I can't find it

Thanks for help in advance

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/develop-your-app/loopback
if you want to connect smth to win application on win 10 you should run

CheckNetIsolation.exe LoopbackExempt -is -n=your application

permanently
the best way to add it to start up menu